# audio Queue - No matching function for call to 'AudioSessionInitialize'

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-audio, audioqueue

I have a problem. I want use some functionality which work with sound in my app.

I found example SpeakHere and include the main part functionality of this app in my app. But I have 3 errors:

> No matching function for call to 'AudioSessionInitialize'

[image]

**How can I fix this bugs?**

I added to project frameworks: coreAudio, AudioToolbox
I use ARC.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a bridging problem as per
[AudioServices.h not found in objective-C iOS project that includes AudioToolbox framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11662426/audioservices-h-not-found-in-objective-c-ios-project-that-includes-audiotoolbox)

Basically you need to use (__bridge void*)self in those 3 places.

Answer (score 6):

```
AudioSessionInitialize(NULL, NULL, interruptionListener, (__bridge void*)self);
```

because you are using *ARC*, so you need to transfer `(void *)` into `(__bridge void*)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you have the following import in your code:

```
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
```

Comment: I did it, but it not fix my problem

Answer (score 0):

Add the AudiToolbox framework to the build phases, then

```
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
```

[image: Build Phases]